# Chartjs equidistance between X values

Tags: date, width, chart.js, scale

I have a problem with my graph, when I plot my Data-Time array, the grid width seems to be not equal, please see the attached picture.
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1baKWiB1zla9eq-evw-CM25b3h8qnZYOI/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please share your code sample not pictures

Answer (score 0):

Ok the solution was to change distribution from 'series' to 'linear'